# How to find Generator Matrix from a given Parity Check Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm given a Parity Check Matrix
\begin{bmatrix}0&1&1&1&1&0&0\\1&0&1&1&0&1&0\\ 1&1&0&1&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
and I have to find the Generator Matrix of it.I spent many days try to solve it but I can't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This parity-check matrix is in the standard form $$[P^T|I_{n-k}]$$

The generator matrix is hence given by
$$G=[I_k|P]=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 1\\ 0& 1& 0& 0& 1& 0& 1\\0& 0& 1& 0& 1& 1& 0\\ 0& 0& 0& 1& 1& 1& 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

You can verify that $GH^T=0$

Comment: thanks you so much, but can you explain step by step how do you solve it :(. I'm just understand a bit

Comment: Since this is in the standard form, just recognize the matrices $P$ and $I$, and then build the matrix $G$ from the transpose of $P$ and the identity matrix with appropriate size. Not so difficult if you follow it carefully.

Comment: I'm now understand, thanks you so much , you're so great !

Comment: You're welcome!